# how to make api calls in reactjs new hook api and share that across components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How to call a restApi  in the new reactjs hook api. 
And reusing the data using useEffects and useState ? 
I want to just reuse the data across components.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function getAdvice(url) {
    fetch(`http://api.adviceslip.com/advice`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err)
}
```

Comment: Yes of course,  thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a custom hook that creates a new piece of state `advice` that you set when your network request has finished.

Return a function from the function given to `useEffect` that cancels your request when the component that uses it re-renders or the component is unmounted. You can also give your `url` in an array as the second argument to `useEffect` to only re-run the network request when the `url` actually changes.

**Example**

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function useAdvice(url) {
  const [advice, setAdvice] = useState(null);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setAdvice(`Use ${url} to get some nice advice`);
      }, 1000);
      
      return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
    },
    [url]
  );

  return advice;
}

function App() {
  const advice = useAdvice("https://google.com");

  return <div>{advice}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```